# CA1821 Remove empty Finalizers

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Why VS complains about this finalizer?

VS 2017 -- `15.3.5`
Microsoft Code Analysis 2017 -- `2.3.0.62003`

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class DisposableClass : IDisposable
    {
#if DEBUG
        ~DisposableClass() // CA1821 Remove empty Finalizers
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail("Forgot Dispose?");
        }
#endif

        public void Dispose()
        {
#if DEBUG
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
#endif
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Comment: So, does this happen in debug or release build? Or in both maybe?

Comment: @Evk: in both, when I change to Release (unchecked DEBUG constant) - text between `if DEBUG` and `endif` is not grayed out.

Comment: According to the documentation for CA1821:  "A type implements a finalizer that is empty, calls only the base type finalizer, **or calls only conditionally emitted methods.**"  In this case `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail` is a conditionally-emitted method because it is decorated with `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]`

Comment: Maybe it's related to that "is not grayed out" thing. Can you ensure that "Define DEBUG constant" is checked in project properties in debug mode and unchecked in release mode?

Comment: @Amy documentation includes case exactly like in OP about how to avoid this warning when using conditional methods (bottom of the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264476.aspx)

Comment: When you say you "change to Release", can you describe the steps you are taking? I have a feeling you think you are changing the configuration but you are not.

Comment: @evk it looks like the example in the documentation is incorrect, then.

Comment: It would appear this is a problem with "Microsoft Code Analysis 2017". The compiler itself does not generate any warnings (but the editor does not gray out the DEBUG block either - only in the .NET Core mode; does gray it out in a traditional .Net  project).

Comment: This looks to be a current [bug in the Analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1241).

Comment: @Eric you should post this as answer I think.

Comment: @Juan: I am doing it correctly, in VS-2017 when I change to Release mode, text between if ... endif is grayed out - but only in .NET Framework. In .NET Core project it does not work! So we have 2 bugs here.

Comment: I just updated VS to 15.4.0 and I cannot reproduce this anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks to be [a bug in the Analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1241).

From the Jun 23 comment in the issue:

> @nguerrera Thanks, you are right that the analyzer is reporting a valid issue on release build. However, there is still an issue in the analyzer - it shouldn't fire if the enclosing method is also conditionally excluded. For example, the following still fires the diagnostic in both release and debug builds.
>
> ```
> #if DEBUG
>     ~InvisibleEditor()
>     {
>         Debug.Assert(Environment.HasShutdownStarted, GetType().Name + " was leaked without Dispose being called.");
>     }
> #endif
> ```

Comment: I think it is the solution. But we have 2 bugs here. Second is that when I change to Release mode, text is grayed out between if...endif but only in NET framework project, not in NET core project...

Comment: I tried that on my machine. The code inside the preprocessor directives should have been grayed out, but was not (VS bug?). However, when I built both configurations and opened them up in ILDASM, you can see that the Finalize() method was excluded from the release assembly.

Comment: if you change to release, and then restart VS, it will gray out. And if you want to change back to Debug, you need also restart VS. But it is just visual effect.